# Populate dynamic month names in ASP.Net DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This article also explains how to add leading zeros to single digit so that it appears as 01, 02….09 when populated in ASP.Net DropDownList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
        {
            string monthName = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(month);
            ddlMonthNames.Items.Add(new ListItem(monthName, month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')));
        }

        for (int month = 1; month <= 12; month++)
        {
            ddlMonths.Items.Add(new ListItem(month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'), month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second DropDownList is simply populated with Months and for single digit months 1-9, leading zero is padded to it so that it appears as 01, 02….09.

Comment: Why so much code. you can just do it like. `int i=1;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("00"));`

Comment: As per my practice,it will not work.So i tried on PadLeft(2, '0').

Comment: And why it won't work in your case. I also want to know such cases.